# Logging with Apache Axis

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, axis, enterprise

I would like to know how to configure my .Ear web application to log all of what Apache Axis is doing. Currently, the time taken for one of my web services is around 3 seconds, and I would like to further investigate what's exactly taking it this much time by enabling the Axis logs. I'm using Jboss 4.2.0 as a webserver and my version of Axis is 1.4. Some forums discussed something about replacing the log4j.properties file inside the axis.jar with a custom one, but I couldn't find it inside the axis.jar. Can anyone give me some heads-up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working. All you have to do is going to the jboss-log4j.xml that's found under {jboss Home}/server/all/conf, and add the following XML values:

```
 <category name="org.apache">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.apache.axis">
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
   </category>
```

By doing so, the logs will be written directly to the server.log file.